# Form and Security in Symfony

Tags: forms, security, symfony

Let's say I want a form so users can change/update their own comments. (comment that they leave for an article for exemple).

Let's say I get all comments linked to an article (comments of any users)... and I incorpore then into a form.

Controller

```
$comments = $em->getrepository('comment')->getAllComments_from_an_article($article); // retrun all comments related to an article whatever the author/users of the comments.
$comments = array('comments' => $comments);
$form = $this->createForm(new CommentsType(), $comments);
```

CommentsType

```
 builder->add('comments','collection', array('type'=> new commentType() ));
```

CommentType

```
 builder->add('comment_text','textarea');
```

Now I display only comment that belong to the current user:

```
{% for comment in form.comments %}
   {% if app.user = comment.user %} {{ form.widget(comment.comment_text) }}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is, **will it be secure like this or there is a risk that the current user might be able to edit comment of other users**?

Comment: Never rely on client side security.  Make yourself a Security Voter http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html and verify their permissions right before actually updating the comment.  Do what you doing so the user only sees their comments but don't rely on it for security.

Comment: ok Cerad, could you make an explanation on how it work. no code but just what voters do (symfony documentation is so abstract)

Comment: @Aleqxs, there's actually all the code you need at the page @Cerad linked to. It gets interesting in the section "Creating the custom Voter". You'll want to adapt the `Voter` so it matches your comment class but it's pretty much all the code you need, then declare that voter as a service. As said in the doc : all voters are called along with the `isGranted` method, so you just need to make that simple check in your controller before actually persisting the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often best to start at the end of the security articles and work backwards. So what you want to achieve is this:

```
class CommmentController
{
    public function editAction($request,$comment)
    {
        if (!$this->isGranted('EDIT',$comment)
        {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
```

So you are tapping in to the existing security system and asking it if the current user is allowed to update the specific comment in question.  Your CommentVoter is what actually decides.

Chopped down a bit, your voter might look like:

```
class CommentVoter implements VoterInterface
{
public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
{
    return in_array($attribute, array('VIEW','EDIT');
}
// Only deal with comments for this voter
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    // Actually better to inject the class name but oh well
    $supportedClass = 'AppBundle\Entity\Comment';

    return $supportedClass === $class || is_subclass_of($class, $supportedClass);
}
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $comment, array $attributes)
{
    // Only deal with comments
    if (!$this->supportsClass(get_class($comment))) {
        return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }
    $user = $token->getUser();

    switch($attributes[0])
    {
      'EDIT':
        // It all comes down to here
        if ($user->getId() === $comment->getUser()->getId()) 
        {
          return VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
      break;
    }
    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
}
```

Wire this up with an entry in your services.yml file: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html#declaring-the-voter-as-a-service

As you might imagine, your voter can be more sophisticated.  For example, admin users might be able to edit all comments.  Easy enough to add the code.

If you implement the VIEW permission then your template becomes:

```
{% for comment in form.comments %}
 {% if is_granted('VIEW',comment.vars.value) %} {{ form.widget(comment.comment_text) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: YES, very well explained... (Symfony documentation is always so tricky... most of the time I do not see the point of their explanation. Guess for people who re used to symfony it is ok). Anyway thanks. one more question: if I implement the voter you described but only the VIEW, would it be secure? if not can I implement it into a form.

Comment: If you consider view and edit to be the same then I suppose so.  Seems a bit strange.

Comment: Can I combine this with a delete collection http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed